# Как найти числа из строки заданного шаблона?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо извлечь из строки вида

```
Memory Working Set Current = X Mb, Memory Working Set Peak = X Mb
```

извлечь числа X. Ограничений на числа X не прописано, но делаю предположение, что это число float (тонкий момент, что я не учитываю int, но он не является предметом вопроса, поэтому опустим этот момент).
Как это сделать?

Я написал следующее:

```
def MFSP(input_string):
    if input_string.startswith("Memory Working Set Current = "):
        return float(re.findall(r'[\d]+[\.][\d]*', input_string)[1])
    else:
        return -1
```

Человек, которому я сдаю код сказал, что поиск по строке является хрупким решением.
Вот иной вариант (но его я даже показывать боюсь):

```
input_string = "Memory Working Set Current = X Mb, Memory Working Set Peak = X Mb"
tmpString_ = re.split(r',', input_string)
if len(tmpString_) != 2:
    print("ERROR")
tmpString_[0] = re.split(r" ", tmpString_[0])
tmpString_[1] = re.split(r" ", tmpString_[1])
print(tmpString_)
if tmpString_[0][0] != "Memory":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[0][1] != "Working":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[0][2] != "Set":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[0][3] != "Current":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[0][4] != "=":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[0][5+1] != "Mb":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[1][0] != "":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[1][1] != "Memory":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[1][2] != "Working":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[1][3] != "Set":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[1][4] != "Peak":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[1][7] != "Mb":
    print("ERROR")
if tmpString_[1][7-1].isdigit() == True:
    print(float(tmpString_[1][7-1]))
else:
    print("ERROR")
```

Как решить эту задачу лаконично и надёжно?

Comment: Забыл сделать проверку, что после второго сплита осталось не более 7 и 8 элементов в каждом списке соответственно, но не будем устрашать код ещё большим количеством громоздких элементов.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что вам необходимо для начала удостоверится, что строка содержит именно заданные слова? Если да, то решение, предложенное ниже Andrey не будет работать.

Comment: Да, только для строк с такими словами, различными могут быть лишь числа.
Причём я хочу найти не просто какое-то решение (оно у меня уже есть), а более-менее оптимальное решение.

Comment: Мне дали такую рекомендацию: "Эти подстроки должны быть частью регулярного выражения, иначе код становится ненадёжным и более сложным."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение с RegEX:

```
pat = re.compile(r'Memory Working Set\s+(?:Current|Peak)\s+=\s+([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)\s+Mb')
```

тесты:

```
In [24]: pat.findall('Memory Working Set Current = 123 Mb, Memory Working Set Peak = 234.56 Mb')
Out[24]: ['123', '234.56']

In [25]: pat.findall('Memory Working Set Current = 0.123 Mb, Memory Working Set Peak = 5 Mb')
Out[25]: ['0.123', '5']
```

Comment: Красиво, конечно, но такое решение сработает и с половиной строки ('Memory Working Set Current = 123 Mb'). А судя по описанию автора, это "хрупкое" решение.

Comment: @strawdog, да, нам бы критерии «хрупкости» выяснить ;-)

Comment: К сожалению, критерия "хрупкости" мне сами не объяснили, но я однозначно почерпну что-то новое здесь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

А что если с помощью `split()` сначала разбить по запятой, потом каждую часть по `=` и так далее, чтобы в итоге добраться до нужных значений?

```
s = 'Memory Working Set Current = 5.3 Mb, Memory Working Set Peak = 200.0 Mb'

nums = [i.split('= ')[1].split(' ')[0] for i in s.split(',')]

print(nums)
# ['5.3', '200.0']

float_nums = [float(n) for n in nums]

print(float_nums)
# [5.3, 200.0]
```

Comment: А через регулярные выражения это сделать можно?

Answer (score 1):

Я не берусь судить о данных вам рекомендациях, по мне так решение от MaxU - лучший вариант. Но, если вам нужно прям, чтоб все было не "хрупко", то тогда могу предложить сделать так:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'Memory Working Set Current\s+=\s+([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)\s+Mb, Memory Working Set Peak\s+=\s+([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)\s+Mb')

def firm_solution(src: str):
    res=pat.findall(src)
    if res and len(res[0])==2:
        return res[0]
    else:
        return False
```

Проверяем:

```
print(firm_solution("Memory Working Set Current = 123 Mb, Memory Working Set Peak = 234.56 Mb"))
#('123', '234.56')
print(firm_solution("Memory Working Set Current = --- Mb, Memory Working Set Peak = 234.56 Mb"))
# False
print(firm_solution("Memory Working Set Current = 123 Mb"))
# False
```

Не стоит, наверное, напоминать, что в случае удачи возвращается кортеж со строковыми переменными.